# Curving chart diagram

Tags: wpf, mvvm, charts

My goal is to have a diagram which look like [this](http://s14.postimg.org/yx2lpafjl/diagramme.jpg)

Each arrow should be a one dimensional chart, where point are displayed (colors and point size depends on some values)

I'm building my own chart system because I spent a few hours looking for one which allow to custom markers (size and colors, and maybe even shape) but I couldn't find one.
Actually the only one I found is [dynamic data display 2.0](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/) which is only proposed in Silverlight.

My biggest problem is the two curving chart I have to do at the top of the diagram. 
I tried to use PathListBox control, but because it's a listBox, I couldn't display items at fixed X position (like using a chart).

I'm not asking for a full perfect solution, but can someone give me advices, or clues ? 
How would you manage to do something like that ?
It should only be a XAML work here, because all the data are already ready in a ListCollectionView (i'm using MVVM).

Thank you !

Comment: You should definitely draw it on Canvas. Data binding can be implemented later.

Comment: My problem is that I can draw the arrow on the canvas, but how can I put the point like I can do on a one dimension chart ?

Comment: Points are Ellipses with 1-2px radius. You can draw them if you calculate their position correctly, though it is not that easy and requires some algorithms.

Comment: OK ellipse's equations aren't that complicated, but I hoped there was a better solution than calculate the pixels positions ... I didn't find even someone talking about it. Anyway thank you vorrtex